# Is there a way to create reusable functions in DAX/Power BI that take calculated measures in as an argument?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm creating page in Power BI with custom KPI visuals (10-15 KPIs) made up of numerous measures for each KPI.
Note: when I say custom KPI visual I mean that each KPI visual is made up of other visuals combined together to appear as one visual, e.g.
an area chart, trending indicator icon (with conditional formatting measure to set the colour), current value, previous value, comparative text showing absolute change and % change, along with a couple of pieces of information

Basically each KPI is reporting a base metric and currently to build the visual(s) I am using 6-7 calculated measures.  Multiply that by 10-15 metrics, I will end up with many calculated measures for this KPI page and a lot of the code will be duplicated for each base metric.

I've looked into using calculation groups but I just do think it will work for this scenario.  Perhaps if I could pass a measure and calculation item as a field into any visual then it might.

It would be nice if I could create calcuation class with methods so that I can pass the base measure into the class using a method to return the derivative measure I need for the visual.
The class would continue all the calculations for the 6-7 pieces of information I need since the calculations for each piece of information are the same for base measure/metric.
Or essentially custom function(s) that take a measure a an argument that I can reuse for the 10-15 KPI metrics.

Something like:
[Total Sales].CurrentValue, [Total Sales].ComparableValue, [Total Sales].TrendIcon, [Total Sales].TrendIconColour, etc.

I'm really trying to avoid creating 70+ calculated measures and would rather just the 6-7 base calculations. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: You can design calculation groups, and then define selected measure as a switch between your measures (i.e, SWITCH True() "Total Sales", [Total Sales], etc)

Comment: [Calculation groups](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/introducing-calculation-groups/) are definitely the way to go. I'd suggest reading about them, trying them out, and then coming back with specific question(s) if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks RADO and Alexis Olson.
It feels like calculation groups is the way to go, however I'm just struggling with how to apply it in my scenario.  I will definitely give the article a good read.